# Embed iframe in Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I was wondering if there is some silverlight control in which I could basically use as an `<iframe>` ... I would like to embed a page into my silverlight application in a panel.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using Telerik controls then you could use the RadFrameContainer & RadFrame to do the job.
also see this thread: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/74271.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there were some nice suggestions and responses here, I am currently working with an Infragistics HTMLViewer for xaml. Right now it is doing everything I need. If anyone else is interested, here is a [link](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/silverlight/xam-web-html-viewer.aspx#Overview).

Answer (score 1):

There is no kind of WebBrowser control for Silverlight. I think your best bet is to run the Silverlight plugin in [windowless mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/cc838156%28v=vs.95%29) and use HTML/CSS to overlay a regular `<iframe>` on top. You could also experiment with making the plugin background transparent and having some sort of regular iframe "show through" from below in a certain area. You would then just need to style appropriately in both Silverlight and CSS and blend them to the point where it is transparent to the user what is really going on.

Here's a [tutorial](https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/using-windowless-silverlight-controls-to-blend-html-and-silverlight-elements) demonstrating blending some HTML with Silverlight.

Be aware that running in windowless mode comes with some [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/silverlight_sdk/limitations-of-windowless-mode-for-silverlight) and a performance hit, as every frame is essentially getting rendered by both the plugin and the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If your question pertains only to Silverlight 3 then it does not have any control to host HTML content.

However, Silverlight 4 introduces the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(VS.95).aspx) control which can be used to host any HTML content. Note that it only works in OOB (out-of-browser) scenarios.

More details from this [post](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-html-hosting-in-the-webbrowser-control.aspx)